# Depth first search infinite loop code

Tags: java, infinite-loop, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve the missionaries and cannibals problem and I'm trying to implement a DFS algorithm to find the best solution. Unfortunately this code takes me to an infinite loop and I don't understand why. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;

public class DFS3 { 

    public State2 exec(State2 root) {       
        if (root==null)
            return null;

        Stack<State2> stack = new Stack<State2>();
        Set<State2> visitedNodes = new HashSet<State2>();
        //Add the root to the stack
        stack.push(root);

        while(!stack.isEmpty()) 
        {
            State2 n = stack.pop();
            //Check to see if node n is the requested node
            if(n.isGoal())          
                return n;
            else
            {
                //Create an array of the leaf nodes to node n
                List<State2> children = n.generateSuccessors();
                for(int i =0; i<children.size(); i++)
                {
                    //Add the leaf nodes to the stack
                    if ( !visitedNodes.contains(children.get(i)) ) {
                        stack.push(children.get(i));
                        visitedNodes.add(children.get(i));
                    }                
                    System.out.println(stack.peek());
                }
            }
        }
        //Not found so return null
        return null;
   }
}
```

And this is how I generate new succesors.

```
public List<State2> generateSuccessors() {
        List<State2> successors = new ArrayList<State2>();
        if (boat == Position.LEFT) {//la dreapta
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL, mL - 2, Position.RIGHT,
                    cR, mR + 2)); // 2 misionari stanga-dreapta
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL - 2, mL, Position.RIGHT,
                    cR + 2, mR)); // doi canibali stanga-dreapta
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL - 1, mL - 1, Position.RIGHT,
                    cR + 1, mR + 1)); // un misionar si un canibal stanga-dreapta
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL, mL - 1, Position.RIGHT,
                    cR, mR + 1)); // un misionar stanga-dreapta
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL - 1, mL, Position.RIGHT,
                    cR + 1, mR)); //un canibal
        } else { //la stanga
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL, mL + 2, Position.LEFT,
                    cR, mR - 2)); 
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL + 2, mL, Position.LEFT,
                    cR - 2, mR)); 
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL + 1, mL + 1, Position.LEFT,
                    cR - 1, mR - 1)); 
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL, mL + 1, Position.LEFT,
                    cR, mR - 1)); 
            testAndAdd(successors, new State2(cL + 1, mL, Position.LEFT,
                    cR - 1, mR)); 
        }
        return successors;
    }

    private void testAndAdd(List<State2> successors, State2 newState) {
        if (newState.isValid()) {
            newState.setParentState(this);
            successors.add(newState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you do not remove items from the stack into the loop. So, your stack is always non empty. And you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Each time you don't find your goal node, you push five `State2` objects onto the stack.  On the next iteration, you test whatever is top of stack  and, if it's not the goal, you push another 5 and so on.  You never test the 4 that you've pushed onto the stack before the 5th that you test.  So your program will potentially loop forever unless your goal state happens to be on the edge of your tree. Try printing `stack.size()` on each iteration.

Comment: This came to me in a help and improvement queue for editing.  As there was not much wrong with the question in itself and the relevant code was there, I've simply tidied up the formatting somewhat.  You could possibly improve the question by explaining what debugging you've tried to do and what the output was (e.g. I see you're printing `stack.peek()` - what was the thinking behind that and what did it output?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this algorithm worked for me.

```
import java.util.*;    

public class DFS2 {
    public static State2 exec(State2 root) {

        boolean found = false; 
        List<State2> visited = new ArrayList<State2>(); 
        Stack<State2> toVisit = new Stack<State2>(); 
        toVisit.push(root);
        while (!toVisit.isEmpty() && !found) {
            State2 nod = toVisit.pop();
            visited.add(nod);

            if (nod.isGoal()) { 
                found = true;               
                return nod;
            }
            else { 
                List<State2> copii=new ArrayList<State2>();
                List<State2> children = new ArrayList<State2>();
                children = nod.generateSuccessors();
                for(int i =0; i<children.size(); i++)
                {
                    //Add the leaf nodes to the stack
                    if ( !visited.contains(children.get(i)) )               
                            copii.add(children.get(i));
                }
                toVisit.addAll(0, copii);
            }
        }
       return null;
}
}
```